# MEDIA_ERR_DECODE in dashif reference player on Chrome 37

Tags: html, google-chrome, mp4, codec, mpeg-dash

Since Chrome (automatically!) updated itself to version 37 (from version 36) I've issues with the Dash reference player from dashif.org

Everything worked like a charm in Chrome version 36, but refuses to play in Chrome version 37, and there is no way to downgrade to the previous version (I've searched Google but can't find it anywhere). There must be some kind of problem with decoding the fragments (Chrome bug?). On my Android tablet, I have both the last stable (36) and beta (37) release, and the player only works in the stable release.

A log from the player:

```
Parsing complete: ( xml2json: 3ms, objectiron: 5ms, total: 0.008s)
Manifest has loaded.
MediaSource is open!
Event {clipboardData: undefined, path: NodeList[0], cancelBubble: false, returnValue: true, srcElement: MediaSource…}
Video codec: video/mp4;codecs="avc3.42c01e,mp4a.40.2"
No text tracks.
Added 0 inline events
Audio codec: video/mp4;codecs="avc3.42c01e,mp4a.40.2"
Duration successfully set to: 17.04
BufferController video seek: 0
BufferController video start.
Waiting for more video buffer before starting playback.
Marking a special seek for initial video playback.
Getting the request for time: 0
Index for time 0 is 0
SegmentList: 0 / 17.04
loaded video:Initialization Segment:NaN (200, 0ms, 23ms)
Initialization finished loading: video
Got loadmetadata event.
Starting playback at offset: 0
element loaded!
Start Event Controller
loaded video:Media Segment:0 (200, 40ms, 2ms)
Video Element Error: MEDIA_ERR_DECODE
MediaError {code: 3, MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1, MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2, MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3, MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4…}
BufferController video stop.
```

The official player (http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.1.2/index.html) with as source the Caption Test, however, still works in Chrome 37. The only difference I see (in the logs), are the codecs (avc3.42c01e instead of avc1.42c01e, mp4a.40.2 instead of mp4a.40.5).

I've encoded the video files with FFMPEG, and DASHed them with MP4box. Chrome 37 is able to play the files outputted by FFMPEG.

Anyone any thoughts on this?

Comment: I filed a bug report with Google: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408552

Comment: Did you finally solve the problem? Were you able to encode the videos so that DASH playback in Chrome works?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed in Canary v40 and upcoming chrome version. and There is a fix in the development branch of dash.js for this issue.